# Filtering an object based on user input

Tags: javascript

I have an object with 29 different plane information.

How do i filter through them to show the given input in a search bar.

ie. input into the search bar = 11000

Expected output, prints the planes that has the same range.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvZG6.jpg)

Comment: you need to add the object which you have, then only one can help you out

Comment: aeroplanes.filter(ob => ob.range>=11000)

Comment: show some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the below filtering logic :)
Now take the value from the userInput, store it in the variable and use in the filtering funtion below like 
`plane.range === userInputValue`

```js
const planes = [
  {
    name: 'Cool Plane',
    range: 11000
  },
   {
    name: 'Nice Plane',
    range: 11001
  },
  {
    name: 'great Plane',
    range: 11000
  },
]

const correctRangePlanes = planes.filter(plane => plane.range === 11000);
console.log(correctRangePlanes)
```

Answer (score 0):

The inferencial code goes as:

```
aeroplanes.filter(ob => ob.range === 11000)
```

Answer (score 0):

It applies only to the range value. If you want also search through other parameters you need to add alternative conditions. to the `filter()`.

```
let searchValue = document.getElementById('search_bar').value;
var filteredPlanes = function(search) { return planes.filter(el => el.range>=parseInt(search)); }
```